# what is the Regex value for 14 digits, the 8th and 9th place is 8

Tags: regex

I want to check 14 digits number if the 8th an 9th place is 8

12345678812345  - true
14758638856555  - true
15454324545455  - false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be the following:
^\d{7}88\d{5}$

Comment: This assumes the complete string is the number, otherwise a different bound is required.

Comment: I don't think you want anchors, but perhaps `(?<!\d)\d{7}88\d{5}(?!\d)`, `(?<!\d)` being a negative lookbehind and `(?!\d)` being a negative lookahead.

Comment: We'll never know without a more detailed question

Comment: I see your point.